# Extension method on Objects

Tags: c#-4.0, bitmap, extension-methods

I am interested in creating an extension method on `Bitmap` object such that I can simply call it like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(...);
bmp.GrayScale();
```

and the resulting `bmp` is in grayscale.

Currently I have an extension method `Bitmap GrayScale(this Bitmap bmp)` but to use it I have to say `bmp = bmp.GrayScale()`

It works, but I wanted to eliminate using `bmp = bmp.` notation.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766923/how-can-you-extend-the-bitmap-class).

Comment: @diiN_ When I do that, my `bmp.GrayScale()` doesn't change the calling object for some reason. However if I return the value and assign it to my original object `bmp = bmp.GrayScale()` it works.

Comment: @DanDef No it's not the same.

Comment: @SollyM I misunderstood what you were asking. You need to ensure that the extension method modifies the `Bitmap` that is passed in. It seems that it is currently creating a new `Bitmap` based on the original and returning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I don't regard this as an answer per se but just the fix to the code that gave me grey hairs.

`@diiN_` was right. The problem with my code was that inside, it created another `Bitmap` object which basically the manipulation of the image was based on. Then returned this object. The Grayscale was not applied on my original object. The link provided was very helpful.

```
public static void SetGrayPalette(this Bitmap bmpImage)
{
    ColorPalette palette = bmpImage.Palette;
    for (int i = 0; i < palette.Entries.Length; i++)
    {
        palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
    }
    bmpImage.Palette = palette;
}
```

Originally, the code was like this:

```
public static void SetGrayPalette(this Bitmap bmpImage)
{
    ColorPalette palette = bmpImage.Palette;
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(bmpImage.Width, bmpImage.Height);
    for (int i = 0; i < palette.Entries.Length; i++)
    {
        palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
    }
    target.Palette = palette;
    return target;
}
```

Comment: This code will not work because target *and* bmp are disposed here. I think you meant to dispose the old `bmp` value. But that's bad style because the caller logically owns the object. Fyi.

Comment: `bmp` is not disposed... it's currently working for me.

Comment: As written the last two lines cause the bitmap in both bmp and target to be disposed (it's the same object). What's your opinion on what these lines do?

Comment: Gosh.... I have messed this one up.... LOL Thanks for pointing it out. This is the `crop` function but what I needed to show here was the `grayscale` function. I will fix this later.